# Angular material - sidenav component not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am developing a web app for different devices : Desktop, Tablet, phone.
I have combined the sidenav and mediaquery (`import {MediaMatcher} from '@ angular / cdk / layout';`) for the device size detection.

When i load a app with a phone size the sidenav opens, but when i change the device size and return to the phone size the sidenav does not open.

How can I solve the problem?

Link of the bugged app: [Editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav121321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Host Listener` to listen to window resize event and make the following changes in your app.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
 event.target.innerWidth < 400 ? this.sideNavButtonVisible = true :  this.sideNavButtonVisible = false;
}
```